# Is there any way to find out what an entire file looked like in a particular commit?

Tags: git

Is there any way to find out what an **entire** file looked like in a particular commit **after applying all changes** to it? I know there is a difference between 2 files(what was added and removed) and that's what shown in git. But that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for `git show revision-id:path/to/file` ?

Comment: @DCoder revision-id - is a part of the command or a filler?

Comment: @Alex: revision-id is a filler. path/to/file is also a filler.

Comment: @DCoder `fatal: reference is not a tree:`

Answer (score 10):

If you know the commit id you can checkout the specific file like below:

```
git checkout <commitid> yourfile
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to modify your local version use:

```
git show <commitid>:filename
```

Comment: will it change the local version of it?

Comment: Yes, it will change the local version. Don't use it.

Comment: Yes it will. If you want to just see what it looked like, use `git show commitid:filename`

Comment: git show commitid:filename - error - fatal: reference is not a tree -

Comment: You've got to use git hash instead of `commitid` and full path to the file from the top of your git repository as the `filename`